# SLAM with pcl data?

Tags: slam, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of now I am using pcl (3 coordinates to specify a point in space) for obstacle avoidance and it seems to work fine. I wish to know that without converting pcl to laser (pointcloud_to_laserscan package) can I develop SLAM ? I am not entirely sure about developing a 2D map with 3D data, any help or suggestions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63129/slam-with-pcl-data-?/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The package [ethzasl_icp_mapping](http://ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping) might be the one you need. Then you could use this package [octopmap_server](http://ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) to get a projected 2D occupancy grid by passing it the registered point cloud from [ethzasl_icp_mapping](http://ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping)

---

Originally posted by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) with karma: 172 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1